# href='News.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>' not work in LinkButton ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, href, linkbutton

i want to use `href='News.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>'` in linkbutton but it is dosent work pleas help me

Comment: href is not a property of a LinkButton, use PostBackUrl as in the answer bellow. The binding is good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
<a href="News.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>">Click me</a>
```

or if you have a LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    runat="server" 
    PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("~/News.aspx?id={0}", Eval("id")) %>' 
    Text="Click me" 
/>
```