# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Dotnetnuke module creation

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have in asp.net a script that gets a product name from the previous page and i get it like this :

```
<%
    strProductID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString("ProductID"))
    strLinkPath = "\DNN7\PRODUCTPDF\" + strProductID + ".pdf"
%>
```

and u assign that id as the pdf name, which is the same. 
I try to download this pdf from this link label:

```
<a runat="server" class="pdfLink" href="<% =strLinkPath %>"><% =strLinkPath %></a>
```

and i get the error `'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '`

If i add the path straight to the label it works fine :

```
strLinkPath = "\DNN7\PRODUCTPDF\1.pdf"
```

Also if i put the dynamic link to be printed in the label i get the same path as the one i setup manually and its the same as this:`"\DNN7\PRODUCTPDF\1.pdf"`  but the dynamic doesnt work and i keep getting this error.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
Server Error in '/DNN7' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedUrlRewriter.Handle404OrException(FriendlyUrlSettings settings, HttpContext context, Exception ex, UrlAction result, Boolean transfer, Boolean showDebug) +165
   DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedUrlRewriter.RewriteUrl(Object sender, EventArgs e) +867
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +91
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +164
```

Comment: The error appears when you click the link ? Witch code are generated On DOM for the <a> element ?

Comment: Yes the error appears when i click the link. You mean this :<a href="../../../../../DesktopModules/MyModules/ProductDetailsModule/%3C%25%20=strLinkPath%20%25%3E" class="pdfLink">\DNN7\PRODUCTPDF\2.pdf</a>?

Comment: I think the error is in the href generated. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348006/href-news-aspxid-evalid-not-work-in-linkbutton-asp-net)

Comment: I dont see how this will help me. I tried a few combinations from this post but i only get redirected to the same page and nothing is doenloaded

Comment: You have a href like this `href="../../../../../DesktopModules/MyModules/ProductDetailsModule/%3C%25%20=str‌​LinkPath%20%25%3E"` this is not a correct link.

Comment: Yes i know. Thats what am trying to fix now. But i cant get a correct path if i dont put it manually. If i put this ~/ in front of the href="~/<% =strLinkPath %>" i get this path   <a href="../../../../../%3C%25#%20Eval(strLinkPath)%20%25%3E" class="pdfLink">PRODUCTPDF/5.pdf</a>  which is a bit better i think. But still i cant fix this  %3C%25#%20Eval(strLinkPath)%20%25%3E

Comment: try to remove `runat='server'` from <a> element

Comment: It worked man. Thank you. I changed my path to this strLinkPath = "/DNN7/PRODUCTPDF/" + strProductID + ".pdf" again and removed the ranut and its fine now. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I removed runat=server and changed my path to this strLinkPath = "/DNN7/PRODUCTPDF/" + strProductID + ".pdf" and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For Me when this error happen always because **SQLSERVER** Instance service not started or need to restart
Steps to solve this problem:
 - open sql server management studio.
 - try to connect to sql instance.
 - right click on instance -> Stop then start again.
OR
 - on windows services search for your instance SQL Server(instance name)
 - right click Stop then start
 refresh your page it should work
hope this help